# Как понять почему ModX передает в collections.renderer.image пустое значение?

Tags: modx

**Движок - MODX Revolution 2.6.1-pl**

**Снипет - Collections 3.6.0-pl**

В коллекции (Collections) есть поле **tv_image** с рендером **collections.renderer.image**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Изображение у элемента коллекции загружено:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но в выводе коллекции в панеле управления поле изображения пустое. Поставив брейкпоинт в js-функции **collections.renderer.image** файла **assets\components\collections\js\mgr\extra\collections.renderers.js** стало ясно, что значение **value** (относительный путь изображения) пустое...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите как это пофиксить?